# postfix: Temporary lookup failure for FQDN

Tags: linux, email, postfix, email-server, telnet

I'm using the FQDN of dur.bounceme.net which I want to resolve(?) to localhost.  That is, I want mail to user@dur.bounceme.net to get delivered to user@localhost.

I've tried following the [Ubuntu guide on this](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Mailman) and seem to be going in circles a bit.

```
root@dur:~#
root@dur:~# postfix stop
postfix/postfix-script: stopping the Postfix mail system
root@dur:~# postfix start
postfix/postfix-script: starting the Postfix mail system
root@dur:~# telnet dur.bounceme.net 25
Trying 127.0.1.1...
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host: Connection refused
root@dur:~#
root@dur:~# telnet localhost 25
Trying 127.0.0.1...
Connected to localhost.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 dur.bounceme.net ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
ehlo dur
250-dur.bounceme.net
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 10240000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
mail from:telnet@dur.bounceme.net
250 2.1.0 Ok
rcpt to:thufir@dur.bounceme.net
451 4.3.0 <thufir@dur.bounceme.net>: Temporary lookup failure
rcpt to:thufir@localhost
451 4.3.0 <thufir@localhost>: Temporary lookup failure
quit
221 2.0.0 Bye
Connection closed by foreign host.
root@dur:~#
root@dur:~# grep telnet /var/log/mail.log
Aug 28 00:24:45 dur postfix/smtpd[18256]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 451 4.3.0 <thufir@localhost>: Temporary lookup failure; from=<telnet@dur.bounceme.net> to=<thufir@localhost> proto=ESMTP helo=<dur>
Aug 28 00:24:58 dur postfix/smtpd[18256]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 451 4.3.0 <thufir@dur.bounceme.net>: Temporary lookup failure; from=<telnet@dur.bounceme.net> to=<thufir@dur.bounceme.net> proto=ESMTP helo=<dur>
Aug 28 00:54:55 dur postfix/smtpd[18825]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 451 4.3.0 <thufir@dur.bounceme.net>: Temporary lookup failure; from=<telnet@dur.bounceme.net> to=<thufir@dur.bounceme.net> proto=ESMTP helo=<dur>
Aug 28 00:55:08 dur postfix/smtpd[18825]: NOQUEUE: reject: RCPT from localhost[127.0.0.1]: 451 4.3.0 <thufir@localhost>: Temporary lookup failure; from=<telnet@dur.bounceme.net> to=<thufir@localhost> proto=ESMTP helo=<dur>
root@dur:~#
root@dur:~# postconf -n
alias_database = hash:/etc/aliases
alias_maps = hash:/etc/aliases, hash:/var/lib/mailman/data/aliases
append_dot_mydomain = no
biff = no
broken_sasl_auth_clients = yes
config_directory = /etc/postfix
default_transport = smtp
home_mailbox = Maildir/
inet_interfaces = loopback-only
mailbox_command = /usr/lib/dovecot/deliver -c /etc/dovecot/conf.d/01-mail-stack-delivery.conf -m "${EXTENSION}"
mailbox_size_limit = 0
mailman_destination_recipient_limit = 1
mydestination = dur, dur.bounceme.net, localhost.bounceme.net, localhost
myhostname = dur.bounceme.net
mynetworks = 127.0.0.0/8 [::ffff:127.0.0.0]/104 [::1]/128
readme_directory = no
recipient_delimiter = +
relay_domains = lists.dur.bounceme.net
relay_transport = relay
relayhost =
smtp_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtp_scache
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtpd_banner = $myhostname ESMTP $mail_name (Ubuntu)
smtpd_recipient_restrictions = reject_unknown_sender_domain, reject_unknown_recipient_domain, reject_unauth_pipelining, permit_mynetworks, permit_sasl_authenticated, reject_unauth_destination
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtpd_sasl_authenticated_header = yes
smtpd_sasl_local_domain = $myhostname
smtpd_sasl_path = private/dovecot-auth
smtpd_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtpd_sasl_type = dovecot
smtpd_tls_auth_only = yes
smtpd_tls_cert_file = /etc/ssl/certs/ssl-mail.pem
smtpd_tls_key_file = /etc/ssl/private/ssl-mail.key
smtpd_tls_mandatory_ciphers = medium
smtpd_tls_mandatory_protocols = SSLv3, TLSv1
smtpd_tls_received_header = yes
smtpd_tls_session_cache_database = btree:${data_directory}/smtpd_scache
smtpd_use_tls = yes
tls_random_source = dev:/dev/urandom
transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/transport
root@dur:~#
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well I'm not sure that I understand the answer Jenny gave in entirety, the question was flawed (of course).  The solution is to use two loopbacks, this will achieve the desired result as demonstrated below:

```
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ swaks --to thufir@localhost
=== Trying localhost:25...
=== Connected to localhost.
<-  220 dur.bounceme.net ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
 -> EHLO dur.bounceme.net
<-  250-dur.bounceme.net
<-  250-PIPELINING
<-  250-SIZE 10240000
<-  250-VRFY
<-  250-ETRN
<-  250-STARTTLS
<-  250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
<-  250-8BITMIME
<-  250 DSN
 -> MAIL FROM:<thufir@dur.bounceme.net>
<-  250 2.1.0 Ok
 -> RCPT TO:<thufir@localhost>
<-  250 2.1.5 Ok
 -> DATA
<-  354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
 -> Date: Sun, 08 Jun 2014 04:24:58 -0700
 -> To: thufir@localhost
 -> From: thufir@dur.bounceme.net
 -> Subject: test Sun, 08 Jun 2014 04:24:58 -0700
 -> X-Mailer: swaks v20130209.0 jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/
 -> 
 -> This is a test mailing
 -> 
 -> .
<-  250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as 2FDAB221E21
 -> QUIT
<-  221 2.0.0 Bye
=== Connection closed with remote host.
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$ swaks --to thufir@dur.bounceme.net
=== Trying dur.bounceme.net:25...
=== Connected to dur.bounceme.net.
<-  220 dur.bounceme.net ESMTP Postfix (Ubuntu)
 -> EHLO dur.bounceme.net
<-  250-dur.bounceme.net
<-  250-PIPELINING
<-  250-SIZE 10240000
<-  250-VRFY
<-  250-ETRN
<-  250-STARTTLS
<-  250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
<-  250-8BITMIME
<-  250 DSN
 -> MAIL FROM:<thufir@dur.bounceme.net>
<-  250 2.1.0 Ok
 -> RCPT TO:<thufir@dur.bounceme.net>
<-  250 2.1.5 Ok
 -> DATA
<-  354 End data with <CR><LF>.<CR><LF>
 -> Date: Sun, 08 Jun 2014 04:25:05 -0700
 -> To: thufir@dur.bounceme.net
 -> From: thufir@dur.bounceme.net
 -> Subject: test Sun, 08 Jun 2014 04:25:05 -0700
 -> X-Mailer: swaks v20130209.0 jetmore.org/john/code/swaks/
 -> 
 -> This is a test mailing
 -> 
 -> .
<-  250 2.0.0 Ok: queued as A7365221E21
 -> QUIT
<-  221 2.0.0 Bye
=== Connection closed with remote host.
thufir@dur:~$ 
thufir@dur:~$
```

Mail to `localhost` and mail to `dur.bounceme.net` are correctly delivered.

I'm unclear on the distinction between a loopback of 127.0.0.1 and 127.0.1.1, as:

> IPv4 network standards reserve the entire 127.0.0.0/8 address block
>   for loopback purposes. That means any packet sent to one of those
>   16,777,214 addresses (127.0.0.1 through 127.255.255.254) will be
>   looped back.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Localhost#Name_resolution

In any event, the specific problem was not caused by either Postfix or Dovecot, as their default configurations, as the mail stack installed by  the http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/mail-stack-delivery package, functions correctly without additional configuration.

I'm unclear as to why a specific IP address is reserved for localhost, but will read further.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you've got the alias for dur.bounceme.net set up wrong - it tries to connect to 127.0.1.1 instead of 127.0.0.1.

Secondly, you need to tell postfix what domain it should consider local. The web page you link to is about setting up a mailing list service; you should take a look at the postfix documentation instead. There's information about what you need to have "fake domains" work at [the readme file](http://www.postfix.org/STANDARD_CONFIGURATION_README.html#fantasy).

Comment: that didn't even register about 127.0.1.1, thanks.

Comment: It's always easier to see someone else's typos that your own :-)

Comment: only I see that `This mapping happens ONLY when mail leaves the machine; not when you send mail between users on the same machine.` which doesn't explain why this mail between users on the same machine failed above.

Comment: Sorry, I misread a little. Have a look at http://www.postfix.org/BASIC_CONFIGURATION_README.html instead, especially the section about what domains to accept mail for.

Comment: This site is for professional sysadmins. If you haven't read the basic documentation for the system you're working with before asking, you will get downvoted.

Comment: Ok, thanks.  I think that the problem is that it's a "vanity" FQDN.  I was looking at something on postfix.org, but they used a different word and I don't see it right now.  On a different note, is there a problem with this question?  it's been downvoted and now I'm banned, apparently it's permanent.